# $scope.someVariable can't be touched

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm new to AngularJS so my mistake might be anywhere in my code and I can't find it. I'm using `$HTTP GET` method to retrieve data that's located in some server /page. After retrieving that data (which is JSON) I want to play with that string to retrieve the data properly, like name: number: and so on. But the thing is once I put that data into `$scope.listOfCompanyUsers` I can't touch it. If I try to `$scope.listOfCompanyUsers.slice(..)` or if I try any other string function on that object my entire webpage crashes. I "`alert()`"'d the `$scope.listOfCompanyUsers` and the result is:

```
<pre>[
  {
    "admin": true, 
    "id": 123, 
    "username": "someName", 
    "last_name": "someLastName", 
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
]</pre><br>
```

What I wanted to do is remove the pre and br tags from that string so I have a pure JSON string that I could play with but again any function I try on `$scope.listOfCompanyUsers` crashes my site. What do I do? I tried var `someOtherVariable = $scope.listOfCompanyUsers` but that variable doesn't work later. I'm adding parts of my code because my mistake might be somewhere else.

**Controller:**

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/someURL'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.listOfCompanyUsers = response.data;
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(response.status);
        });
```

**Later on the same controller:**

```
.
.
$scope.someFunction = function () {
        .
        .
        else {
            alert("Maximum of 9 other passengers!");
            alert($scope.listOfCompanyUsers);
            // In this alert I could see the $scope.listOfCompanyUsers as mentioned above
        }
    };
```

My target right now is to have a var objectOfUsers = `[{admin: true, id:123, username: "name", last_name: "test", name: "something"}, {next user.}, .]` but because I can't touch the `$scope.listOfCompanyUsers` I'm stuck.

Comment: Instead of `alert($scope.listOfCompanyUsers);`, can you provide us with a screenshot of the result of `console.log($scope.listOfCompanyUsers);`?

Comment: It shows exactly the same, I'll attach a SS anyway.
http://imgur.com/a/wQzGj

Comment: Ah, I see. The `pre` and `br` tags are actually part of the response... Do you have access to the server-side of that call?

Comment: Yes, it's written in python:
webapp2.Route('/ListCompanyUsers', Users.ListCompanyUsers)
I have access and honestly I have absolutely no idea how the server side works, but this is the code I was told to use if I want to move to different URLs through the $http.

Comment: You're going to have to edit the server-side code, though, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the server is adding some extra tags to the response that shouldn't be in there:

```
<pre>[
  {
    "admin": true, 
    "id": 123, 
    "username": "someName", 
    "last_name": "someLastName", 
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
]</pre><br>
```

Edit your server-side code, to remove: `<pre>` and `</pre><br>`.

Then the call will work.

Comment: Yep, actually changing the code at server-side worked and now $scope.listOfCompanyUsers is a json object.

I changed some line that was "self.response.write(<pre>%s</pre><br> % json.dumps(user_list, indent=2))"
to "self.response.write(json.dumps(user_list, indent=2))"

Comment: @LironIlayev: yea, that makes sense :-) Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Is your response a string? If your response has HTML tags, then that is not valid JS object format. It looks like you have a Javascript array with one object, enclosed by some HTML tags.

Therefore you won't be able to access anything within this using the object reference notation (`.`) until you treat it like a string and use `String.prototype.replace` and replace the tags, and then do a `JSON.parse` on the remaining string to convert it into an object

Comment: I put alert(typeof $scope.listOfCompanyUsers); and it says string

Answer (score 0):

Very strange server response, so possible solutions are:

1. Change server response to standard JSON without unwanted `<pre>`
2. If You can not change response remove not wanted part of response using regular expression in JS. Working example how do that:

```js
var response='<pre>[{"admin": true, "id": 123, "username": "someName","last_name": "someLastName", "name": "John Doe"}]</pre><br>';

var goodResponse=response.match(/>([^<]*)</)[1];//remove not wanted signs
var parsedGoodResonse=JSON.parse(goodResponse);
console.log(parsedGoodResonse);//here we have parse js array
```

In `parsedGoodResonse` You have object which can be "touched" so exactly what You need.

Comment: I'd use a simple replace, instead of a regex. Much more reliable.

Comment: @Cerbrus to do this in one line regex would be needed also with replace.

Comment: No regex is needed: `var fixed = response.replace('<pre>', '').replace('</pre><br>', '');` That said, this shouldn't be fixed client-side.

Comment: Ok maybe not one line, but without looking for every not wanted element. So in Your proposition you must enter every not wanted string and replace by '', so if it would be more then I think it is not so good solution. Next thing i sad if first point that it should be on server side.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. The problem in this question is _very_ specific. There's no need to use regexes if you know _exactly_ what you need to remove. If the JSON were to contain a `<`, your solution would break. The simple replace would still "work", even though it really shouldn't be fixed in the front end.

Comment: @Cerbrus I could answer simple as You do, but I wanted to show it is possible also on client side if server side can't be change. This question is not worth my and your time. Giving everyone -1 because they wanted to show how to help on client side was also unnecessary. One thing more, when I answer I never give others -1, because it looks not right.

Comment: You don't know who voted for those answers. Maybe it was me, maybe it was not.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the extra tags is not on your code, it's on the server-side. You should check the code on the server and find the reason for those extra tags. They can't be there because they are making the response an invalid JSON.

Comment: Angular automatically parses the JSON.